# Arch Linux with an nginx/django setup refuses to display ANYTHING

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, web-server, django, arch-linux

I'm on Amazon Ec2, with an Arch Linux server. While I truly am loving it, I'm having the issue of actually getting nginx to display anything. Everytime I try to throw my hostname into the browser, the browser states that it's not available for some reason - almost as if the host doesn't even exist.

One thing I'd like to know is, how can I get this up and running? Is there a specific arch linux configuration I have to do to make it web accessible? I have port 80 open, as well as port 22. I've tried using gunicorn, python-flup, and nginx.

**Nginx Config**

```
user  http;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

   server {

    listen      80;
    server_name _;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    #charset koi8-r;

    location ^~ /media/ {
        root /path/to/media;
    }   

    location ^~ /admin-media/ {
        root /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media;
    }

    location / {

        root /path/to/root/;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_index index.html;

        index index.htm index.html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /etc/nginx/html/50x.html;
    }

   }


   # server {
   #     listen       80;
   #     server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

  #      location / {
   #         root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
     #   }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        #}

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    #}


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

I can't quite tell if it's a server issue or a configuration issue: I've followed so many guides now I can't even count them all. The thing is that Django itself *is* working fine, and my permissions to the document root of the where the site files are stored is 777. Ontop of that, I have a git repo which works perfectly fine, and django, python, and `runfcgi` all start without issues. The same goes for `gunicorn`, when I do a `gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0:8000` in my document root.

Here is my output from that:

```
2012-04-15 05:17:37 [3124] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.2
2012-04-15 05:17:37 [3124] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (3124)
2012-04-15 05:17:37 [3124] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2012-04-15 05:17:37 [3127] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3127
```

As far as I know, everything seems fine, as well as `error.log` and `access.log` for nginx. The access log is completely blank, for that matter.

I just feel lost here; what would be a step in the right direction to bebugging an issue such as this?

Comment: a) Try the IP address instead of hostname (also do you mean the EC2 public DNS or a domain name?) b) verify the port is open (e.g. using `nmap` remotely) - you need to open it on both iptables (`iptables -nvL` to check) and the security group (`ec2-describe-group`) c) verify that nginx is listening on the correct address and port (using `netstat -anp | grep nginx`) d) try to fetch a (static) file from the instance itself using `curl` - all your tests should be static files (bypassing django/gunicorn) before you try dynamic to narrow the problem e) increase error_log verbosity to info or notice

Comment: I mean the ec2 domain name, but I just tried it with an elastic IP address and no dice either. Also, iptables appears to not giving me any output at all: do you have any idea what this means?

Comment: `iptables v1.4.12.2: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)`

Comment: I got it working! Thank you, `ec2-describe-group` is what did it.

Comment: Good to know you got it working - the security group was what I was leading towards. Post your solution and explanation as an answer and close out the question.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I had thought that port 80 was open (as I remember enabling it before). The issue was simply that it was closed.

So, on the local machine, all I did was type

`ec2-authorize default -p 80`

Where `-p` is the port directive, and `default` is the name of the security group.